# filtro between to_timestamp(to_char(now()

Tags: postgresql

Tengo éste filtro

```
ui.inserted_at between to_timestamp(to_char(now() - interval '1 day', 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
and to_timestamp(to_char(now() - interval '1 day', 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

pero necesito restarle 5 horas por que el servidor donde esta la BD está 5 horas adelantado de la zona horario en donde se ejecuratá la consulta

Comment: Tal vez te sirva `interval '29 hours'`.

Comment: el filtro es para un reporte diario del dia anterior por lo que se debe ejecutar a las 12:01 y arrojar registros solo de las 24 horas anteriores pero  el servidor esta 5 horas adelantado, crees que tu recomendación me funcione?

Comment: Si son los datos los que están desfasados 5 horas con respecto a la hora de `now()`, entiendo que si, usa este desplazamiento de 5 horas para el desde/hasta, es decir 29 y 5 horas.